# NSPredicate throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift3, nspredicate

I'm trying to delete books that user selected and I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS at NSPredicate line. Can anyone tell me where am I doing wrong?

```
 func deleteSelectedBook() {
    // Create Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "BookEntity")

    // Create array string for predicate
    var titleCollection:[String] = []
    var formatString:String = ""
    if let selectedCellCollection = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        for index in selectedCellCollection{
            if (!formatString.isEmpty) {
                formatString += " OR "
            }
            var temp = (self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index)?.textLabel?.text)!
            titleCollection.append(temp)
            formatString += " title = %@ "
        }
    }

    // Configure Fetch Request
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: formatString, titleCollection)

 ......
```

Comment: What values do you have for `formatString` and `titleCollection` at that point?

Comment: It was stupid of me. I was using the NSPredicate that takes a string instead of array of string, and Martin correctly pointed that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two (as an example) selected items the `formatString` would be

```
"title = %@ OR title = %@"
```

which expects two arguments, but in

```
NSPredicate(format: formatString, titleCollection)
```

only one argument is given. You *could* fix that with

```
NSPredicate(format: formatString, argumentArray: titleCollection)
```

where the `titleCollection` now provides all arguments for the
predicate creation. But a better and simpler solution is

```
NSPredicate(format: "title IN %@", titleCollection)
```

with a fixed predicate format string.

Generally one should avoid to use string manipulation to create
predicate format strings. In this case a simple predicate serves
the same purpose. In more complicated cases, `NSCompoundPredicate`
can be used to build a predicate dynamically.

Comment: I didn't know I can just create the predicate string I want with one call. Thank you!